# Linq Query of active child entities

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I didn't know what to write in the title of the question. Here's my sample. I have a Foo class which has a collection of Bars as follows:

```
public class Foo  
{  
    public bool Active {get; set;}  
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;}  
}  

public class Bar
{
    public bool Active {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see both Foos and Bars can be set as inactive `(Active = false)`. I nee to write a service (RIA) which will return every active Foo with its actives Bars.
So this is what I have so far:

```
public IQueryable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
    return ObjectContext.Foos.Where(f => f.Active)
                             .Include("Bars");
}
```

The thing is that the above query returns every active `Foo` with every single `Bar`, so how do I include **only** active `Bars` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Include method is part of LazyLoading. Lazy loading is either all or nothing, thus you can not tell the EF to only load some Bars.

What you can try to do, however, is using an anonymous object as a result:

```
context.Foos
.Where(f => f.Active)
.Select(f => new { Foo = f, Bars = f.Bars.Where(b => b.IsActive });
```

Answer (score 1):

EF is not making this easy because it goes against the philosophy of how EF is designed to work. If it was easy to write this query so that the `Bars` collection of each `Foo` entity only contained 'active' `Bar` entities, then each `Foo` entity would not be an accurate model of the state of the database.

On the other hand, if you write the query using a projection (instead of retrieving the Foo entities directly) you have greater flexibility. For example, you could write the query this way:

```
var query =
    from f in ObjectContext.Foos
    where f.Active
    select new { Foo = f, ActiveBars = f.Bars.Where(b=>b.Active)}
```

At this point you *could* write a foreach loop to re-associate the active `Bar` entities with each `Foo` entity:

```
var results = query.ToList();

foreach (var r in results)
    r.Foo.Bars = r.ActiveBars;
```

And finally execute a LINQ query locally to return the results:

```
return (from r in results select r.Foo).ToList();
```

I think the strategy I've just outlined would work just fine for a display-only scenario, but I'd be hesitant to try to update entities retrieved in this fashion.